# List Comprehension is not None AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, error-handling, list-comprehension

```
Date,Amount,Subcategory,Memo,
29/10/2021,953.76,DIRECTDEP,Stripe Payments UK    STRIPE       BGC,
29/10/2021,-1260.44,FT,DIESEL INJECTORS U    TRANSFER          FT,
29/10/2021,-509.15,FT,TNT                   002609348          FT,
```

Above is some accounts data that I need to group, and later apply labels to.

Firstly I tried this `df['Suppliers'] = [re.search(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', item).group(0) for item in df['Memo'] if item is not None]`

But get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` I understand that this is because the pattern was not found in the data.

So I tried removing the `.group(0)` and get a match object for each item respectively e.g `<re.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='Stripe'>`

Question: I am not sure why `if item is not None` doesn't skip over those items where no match is found. And why if I am returned a match object that I can't access with `.group(0)`

I have figured out a solution with a loop, but I would really like to understand what the problem is with the list comp approach.

```
for item in df['Memo']:
    match = re.search(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', item)
    try:
        my_list.append(match.group(0).lower())
        df['Suppliers'] = pd.DataFrame({'Suppliers': my_list})
    except AttributeError:
        my_list.append('na')
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `if item is not None` you check if the `item` is not *`None`*, not the result of the `re.search(r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', item)` operation.

Just use `Series.str.extract` directly:

```py
df['Suppliers'] = df['Memo'].str.extract(r'\b([a-zA-Z]{3,})\b')
```

Mind you need to use a pair of unescaped parentheses to form a capturing group in the pattern when you want to use with with `Series.str.extract`.

If you want to add the `na` as string for the cases where no match was found add `.fillna`:

```py
df['Suppliers'] = df['Memo'].str.extract(r'\b([a-zA-Z]{3,})\b').fillna('na')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's great! What happens if no match is found? It just ignores it?

Comment: @MartyHewing You will get `np.NaN`s by default, but you can use `filllna` as in my answer.

Comment: @MartinHewing Sorry, I made a typo in `fillna`. New keyboard, you know 